# Lodash or Something is behaving differently on my published server

Tags: angularjs, lodash

For some reason I am getting different behaviours from my local server compared to my published online server. At first I thought it could be gulp's uglify that did something, which I turned of as a test. Because the problem happens during a lodash loop I presumed it could be the lodash library, which I then overwrote and re-downloaded the latest version. But the strangest thing is happening when I run this function and debug it, on my local web server the function returns false as expected, but on the online server it returns true. 
I am really scratching my head here because to me that function should return false when passing the value 'o' as you can see from my screenshots during the debugging, it is returning true on the published server.

```
function is_leave(symbol) {
            var symbols = {
                AB: "Absent",
                PS: "Paid Sick Leave",
                US: "Unpaid Sick Leave",
                L: "Paid Leave",
                UL: "Unpaid Leave",
                FL: "Family Responsibility Leave",
                SB: "Standby",
                IOD: "Injury on Duty",
                ML: "Maternity Leave",
                Tr: "Training",
                MC: "Management Counceling",
                C1: "Custom 1",
                C2: "Custom 2",
                C3: "Custom 3"
            };
            _.forEach(nws, function (val, key) {
                if (symbols[key] === undefined) {
                    symbols[key] = val.title;
                }
            });
            var is = false;
            _.forEach(symbols, function (val, key) {
                if (key === symbol) is = true;
            });
            return is;
        };
```

[image]

**Local server**

[image]

Comment: 1. Where is `nws` defined? 2. It might have to do with the ordering of the keys. I don't know if Javascript guarantees the order of the keys of an object when iterating

Comment: Did you check package versions? If you have loose version constraints, there's a risk that the packages contain breaking changes. Always use strict version constraints and/or package-lock.json

Comment: Come to think of it, that iteration over nws doesn't do anything, so I commented that out. Haha, that was actually breaking it... Sometimes one just needs to step away take a break and look at it again, also some direction from Stackoverflow users always helps! Thanks!